# PayPal issues on different iPhone models

Tags: ios, iphone, paypal

I use PayPal in my iOS app. When I run the app on the iPhone 4s it works perfectly, but when I run the app on the iPhone 5s or iPhone 6s the app crashes. This is the error:

```
2016-08-09 11:51:56.241 Signalyx[64835:356737] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[NSTaggedPointerString getCharacters:range:]: Range {0, 7} out of bounds; string length 4'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109138f45 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000108756deb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109138e7d +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010912468a -[NSTaggedPointerString getCharacters:range:] + 394
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109011eaa CFStringCompareWithOptionsAndLocale + 2970
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109124feb -[NSTaggedPointerString compare:options:range:locale:] + 219
    6   Foundation                          0x00000001082ecee3 -[NSString compare:options:range:] + 29
    7   Signalyx                            0x00000001054d328f __53-[PPZebraLocalizer localizeString:adaptedForCountry:]_block_invoke + 60
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010906813b -[NSArray indexOfObject:inSortedRange:options:usingComparator:] + 491
    9   Signalyx                            0x00000001054d2fd4 -[PPZebraLocalizer localizeString:adaptedForCountry:] + 426
    10  Signalyx                            0x00000001054d3a44 PPZebraLocalizedStringWithAlert + 1044
    11  Signalyx                            0x00000001054c1da3 +[PPZebraUI localizedStringForKey:adaptedForCountry:] + 140
    12  Signalyx                            0x00000001054c2de1 +[PPZebraUI cancelBarButtonWithTarget:withAction:] + 88
    13  Signalyx                            0x00000001054b0c01 -[PPDeviceCheckViewController viewDidLoad] + 292
    14  UIKit                               0x0000000106d46cc4 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1198
    15  UIKit                               0x0000000106d47013 -[UIViewController view] + 27
    16  UIKit                               0x0000000106d991c5 -[UINavigationController preferredContentSize] + 194
    17  UIKit                               0x0000000106d1df26 -[UIPresentationController preferredContentSizeDidChangeForChildContentContainer:] + 59
    18  UIKit                               0x0000000106d1a2b4 __56-[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState]_block_invoke + 95
    19  UIKit                               0x0000000106bc01ba _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 317
    20  UIKit                               0x0000000106bd3396 _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 95
    21  UIKit                               0x0000000106bdf1c2 _afterCACommitHandler + 90
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109064947 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001090648b7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010905a50b __CFRunLoopRun + 1147
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109059e08 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    26  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010bf10ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
    27  UIKit                               0x0000000106bb430d UIApplicationMain + 171
    28  Signalyx                            0x00000001053656af main + 111
    29  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010970192d start + 1
    30  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: It looks like a localisation thing, I'm guessing the phones have different locales set.

Comment: Actually I am running my app on iPhone 5s and iPhone 4s simulator.

Comment: Hey please check my answer and let me know.

Comment: I have also add https://github.com/card-io/card.io-iOS-SDK library.But after adding these i have so many error. how i can use this?

Answer (score 0):

I hope there is card.io SDK installed in your app with PayPal. If you check files in your project you will get CardIO files. In that you are using old version of card.io SDK. This issue has been fixed in version 5.1.0. 
[Here is the issue](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-iOS-SDK/issues/120)

**Fixed :**

https://github.com/card-io/card.io-iOS-source/commit/b9b3c0a329b75d048a20190f8843da4f247d755a

The current version of card.io SDK is 5.3.2 and that you need to use. I hope this will resolve your issue.

**For more info refer :**

https://github.com/card-io/card.io-iOS-SDK